# How to add transition to pseudo element on a image tag?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a transition to the image tag when hovering. On hover the image shows a gradient overlay, but not smooth. I tried to add:

```
transition: background 1s ease;
```

but it doesn't work.

```css
.teammember {
  height: 283px;
}

.teammember:hover .teammember-details {
  display: block;
}

.teammember:hover .teammember-photo:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6) 0%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6)), color-stop(100%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6) 0%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6) 0%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6) 0%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6) 0%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3870a7', endColorstr='#f1a80c', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}

.teammember .teammember-photo {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: inherit;
}

.teammember .teammember-photo:before {
  transition: background 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="teammember">
  <div class="teammember-photo">
    <img class="teammember-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="Image">
    <div class="teammember-details">
      <div class="teammember-details-top">
        <strong>Name</strong>
        <p>Function</p>
      </div>
      <div class="teammember-linkedin">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><span class="linkedin"></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I add a transition to the image tag when hovering?

Comment: use opacity:0 to 1 on hover instead display:inline-block

Comment: @Roy thanks that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't transition gradients (yet). The workaround is to transition it's `opacity`.

There was another issue with your CSS - most the styles for the `:before` psuedo element were in the `.teammember:hover` state. Move those to the base `.teammember .teammember-photo:before` selector.

Like this:

```css
.teammember {
  height: 283px;
}

.teammember:hover .teammember-details {
  display: block;
}

.teammember .teammember-photo:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6) 0%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6)), color-stop(100%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6) 0%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6) 0%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6) 0%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6) 0%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3870a7', endColorstr='#f1a80c', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
 
}

.teammember:hover .teammember-photo:before {
   opacity: 1;
}

.teammember .teammember-photo {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="teammember">
  <div class="teammember-photo">
    <img class="teammember-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="Image">
    <div class="teammember-details">
      <div class="teammember-details-top">
        <strong>Name</strong>
        <p>Function</p>
      </div>
      <div class="teammember-linkedin">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><span class="linkedin"></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I didn't know that transitions doesn't work with gradients. :)

Comment: @can Great! Don't forget to accept the solution that solves your question.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are actually applying all the necessary styles to the `:before` pseudo element only when the parent is hovered on. You should simply apply these styles + `opacity: 0` on the ground state (without hover), and then simply toggle `opacity: 1` in the `:hover` state.

In other words, all the styles defined for `.teammember:hover .teammember-photo:before` should simply be moved to `.teammember .teammember-photo:before`. The selector `.teammember:hover .teammember-photo:before` should only be used to change the opacity property.

```css
.teammember {
  height: 283px;
}

.teammember:hover .teammember-details {
  display: block;
}

.teammember:hover .teammember-photo:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.teammember .teammember-photo {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: inherit;
}

.teammember .teammember-photo:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6) 0%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3) 100%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="teammember">
  <div class="teammember-photo">
    <img class="teammember-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="Image">
    <div class="teammember-details">
      <div class="teammember-details-top">
        <strong>Name</strong>
        <p>Function</p>
      </div>
      <div class="teammember-linkedin">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><span class="linkedin"></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Terry for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `opacity` instead of `display`

```css
.teammember {
  height: 283px;
}

.teammember:hover .teammember-details {
  display: block;
}

.teammember .teammember-photo:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6) 0%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6)), color-stop(100%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6) 0%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6) 0%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6) 0%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(56, 112, 167, 0.6) 0%, rgba(241, 168, 12, 0.3) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3870a7', endColorstr='#f1a80c', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s ease-in;
}

.teammember:hover .teammember-photo:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.teammember .teammember-photo {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="teammember">
  <div class="teammember-photo">
    <img class="teammember-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="Image">
    <div class="teammember-details">
      <div class="teammember-details-top">
        <strong>Name</strong>
        <p>Function</p>
      </div>
      <div class="teammember-linkedin">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><span class="linkedin"></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible but there are ways to achieve this.

I found a really well-written article by Mr Dave Lunny which address this topic.

see here: https://medium.com/@dave_lunny/animating-css-gradients-using-only-css-d2fd7671e759

I hope this was helpful.